# RestEasy file upload with progress

Tags: jsf, jboss, seam, resteasy

When posting a file to a resteasy service, something similar to this blog post http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-resteasy/

What is the best way to track the progress of the bytes received by the server, as in a progress bar for the file upload?

Comment: FYI: I ended up using uploadify for this, it works using HTML5 in browsers which support it, and falls back to flash for older browsers.